# Monaca build does not bundle all css and lib folder inside www

Tags: monaca

I have started my monaca project using "minimal template" as base.
And developed further using Monaca localKit.

On local setup, I included onsen library manually. All works fine when I debug using monaca debugger.

But when I build project (either debug or release) onsen library does not get bundled.

Please suggest how to force monaca build to including all files in www folder.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you uploaded the updated files to Monaca server? If you make local changes, you need to upload them to Monaca first before building your app.

Comment: Yes, I have synced all files to online account and after uploading all files reconfirmed using online IDE that all files are there.
But still it does not include/bundle all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it solved myself. Sharing the solution if anyone else got similar issue.

Monaca LocalKit upload does not sync well. It does upload all files and online IDE does show all files are there. But some connection is missing with Monaca Build service.

I uploaded all Files manually with folder structure inside www folder using Monaca web IDE.

Steps:

1) Open Monaca Web IDE, right click on "www" folder and select Upload option, upload window will open which say "drag and drop files here"..

2) In file Explorer, select all files and folder inside "www" of my localKit project, drag and drop it on Monaca Web IDE upload window.

3) After Upload completes, Now try Build for android and this time, APK file will bundle all missing resource in 'www' and on installing on phone, it will work perfectly fine.

I hope this will save someone a day until Monaca fixes its localkit upload/sync issue.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same issue, fixed it the same way. The dev team should be aware, but not sure if they're fixing it.